# How to force all nodes in the same column in graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to model a certain flow using graphviz, and I can't figure out how to model the following graph to share the same horizontal center

```
digraph exmp {
   A -> B -> C -> D
   C -> E [constraint=false]
   A -> C [style="dotted", constraint=false]
   A -> D [style="dotted",  constraint=false]
   B -> D [constraint=false]
   D -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]
   C -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]


   subgraph cluster_hackToSinkIt { E -> F }
   { rank="sink" E F }
}
```

this results in the following graph:

[image: rendered image]

My question is, how can I get the E -> F to be positioned under D such that is lies in the same column?

Comment: The image is broken now. I tried to recreate it, but I get errors from graphviz

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At least [as of May 2007](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2007q2/004428.html), you can't force "columns" *per se*, but you *can* apply *weight* to edges which should help force alignment.  But actually, in this case, if you just add an invisible edge from D to E, you've got vertical alignment.

```
digraph exmp {
    A -> B -> C -> D
    C -> E [constraint=false]
    A -> C [style="dotted", constraint=false]
    A -> D [style="dotted",  constraint=false]
    B -> D [constraint=false]
    D -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]
    C -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]
    D -> E [style="invis"] // <---- important new line


    subgraph cluster_hackToSinkIt { E -> F }
    { rank="sink" E F }
}
```

[image: fixed dot image]

I'm not aware of any way to force edges to one side or another.

Comment: I've removed the question about how to force the edges and will create a new question for that. Else it would be hard to judge which answer would be the correct answer.