# How to force position of edges in graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I'm having problems with edges overlapping each other. In my [previous question of how to force the nodes to be in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476241/how-to-force-all-nodes-in-the-same-column-in-graphviz), found out how to force the nodes in to one column, but this causes some other problems to appear.

```
digraph exmp {
  A -> B -> C -> D -> E
  C -> F [constraint=false]
  A -> C [style="dotted", constraint=false]
  A -> D [style="dotted",  constraint=false]
  B -> D [constraint=false]
  D -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]
  C -> A [style="dashed", constraint=false]
  E -> F [style="invis"] 
  F -> G
  E -> C [constraint="false"]
}
```

Renders to:

[alt text http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/8324/wrong2.gif](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/8324/wrong2.gif)

My problem is that the edges from E -> C and C -> F are starting/ending at the same point in the node C and the dashed and dotted edges are all on the right side of the nodes.

How could I tell specific edges to go to the right side of the node?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a message in the graphviz mail list I've found that's at least possible to remove the E -> C and C -> F overlapping problem.

> The simplest solution is to use a
>   compass point port:
>
> `C:e -> F [constraint=false]`
>
> -- Emden