# How can I direct edge to get out of the diamond on the right?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a simple dot diagram to show how to perform tests.

```
PerformTests;                                     PerformTests<---+
PerformTests -> TestsPassed;                            |         |
TestsPassed [shape="diamond"];                          v         |
TestsPassed -> Release [label="Yes"];             TestsPassed     |
TestsPassed -> FixErrors [label="No"];                 Y|  N\     |
FixErrors -> PerformTests;                              v    FixErrors
                                                     Release
```

The diagram shows square boxes for all nodes, except TestPassed that has a diamond shape. My issue is here. I'd like the edge that goes outside of the diamond for No to be getting out of the diamond at the right (east) instead of oblique down-right (south-east).

```
           What I have        What I want
                ^                  ^    
               / \                / \   
              <   >              <   >--->  
               \ /\               \ /   
                v  \               v
```

I've seen such `compass_pt` in the dot grammar, but cannot figure out how to use it. I what I want possible, and how to do it?

Comment: Does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477532/how-to-force-position-of-edges-in-graphviz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply add the compass_pt `:e` right after the node name in the edge declaration (line 5).

```
PerformTests;                                     PerformTests<-----+
PerformTests -> TestsPassed;                            |           |
TestsPassed [shape="diamond"];                          v     N     |
TestsPassed -> Release [label="Yes"];             TestsPassed --> FixErrors
TestsPassed:e -> FixErrors [label="No"];               Y|  
FixErrors -> PerformTests;                              v
                                                     Release
```

Compass point `e` stands for East (on the right side). Use `w` for the left side (West). There is also `ne` for North-East and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to try using the `constraint='false'` attribute:

http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/constraint.html